# Посчитать количество выполненных циклов в JS

Tags: javascript, циклы

Есть цикл, который должен работать, пока не будет выполнено условие, без установленного количества итераций. Возможно ли вывести количество выполненных операций, и, если да, то как?

```
let income = 3333;
let palmTreeCost = 8000;
let expenses = 1750;
let profit = income - expenses;
while (true) {
    if (profit < palmTreeCost) {
        profit = profit + profit;
        alert(profit);
        if (profit > palmTreeCost) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно добавить переменную (`iteration_num`) и прибавлять к ней единицу на каждой итерации цикла.

```js
let income = 3333;
let palmTreeCost = 8000;
let expenses = 1750;
let profit = income - expenses;

let iteration_num = 0;

while (true) {
  if (profit < palmTreeCost) {
    profit = profit + profit;
    console.log(profit);
    iteration_num++;
    if (profit > palmTreeCost) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log('Iterated ' + iteration_num + ' times!')
```